# Kafka s3 sink connector - many jsons in one json

Tags: json, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm having an issue with the s3 sink connector. I set my flush-size to 3 (for tests) and my s3 is receiving properly the json file. But when I open the json, I don't have a list of jsons, I only have one after other. Is there any way to get "properly" the jsons in a list when they are sent to my bucket? I want to try a "good way" to solve that, else I'll fix this in a lambda function (but I wouldn't like to do it...)

What I have:

```
{"before":null,"after":{"id":10230,"nome":"John","idade":30,"cidade":"São Paulo","estado":"SP","sexo":"M"}
{"before":null,"after":{"id":10231,"nome":"Alan","idade":30,"cidade":"São Paulo","estado":"SP","sexo":"M"}
{"before":null,"after":{"id":10232,"nome":"Rodrigo","idade":30,"cidade":"São Paulo","estado":"SP","sexo":"M"}
```

What I want

```
[{"before":null,"after":{"id":10230,"nome":"John","idade":30,"cidade":"São Paulo","estado":"SP","sexo":"M"},
{"before":null,"after":{"id":10231,"nome":"Alan","idade":30,"cidade":"São Paulo","estado":"SP","sexo":"M"},
{"before":null,"after":{"id":10232,"nome":"Rodrigo","idade":30,"cidade":"São Paulo","estado":"SP","sexo":"M"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The S3 sink connector sends each message to S3 as its own message.

You're wanting to do something different, which is to batch messages together into discrete array objects.

To do this you'll need some kind of stream processing. For example, you could write a Kafka Streams processor that would process the topic and merge each batch of *x* messages into one message holding an array as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear how you expect to read these files other than manually, but most analytical tools that read S3 buckets (Hive, Athena, Spark, Presto, etc), all **expect** [JSONLines](http://jsonlines.org/examples/)

Comment: I solve the problem with some "workarounds". I want to send this data to Power BI streaming dataset (via rest api). So, I have to send one record (json) for post. The best way is to put all jsons in a list and start a loop to sending the data to pbi.

Comment: I would suggest using Hive-Kafka or Presto then hooking PowerBI into that.